# Cannot debug Silverlight project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, silverlight-5.0, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-debugging

Please bear with me as I am new to Silverlight development. I am writing a web api wrapper in my Silverlight project which is supposed to consume rest web services. Below is the method in the api wrapper which I want to debug:

```
    public static T Get<T>(Dictionary<string, string> dictionary, string controller)
    {
        try
        {
            string absoluteUrl = BaseUrl + controller + "?";
            absoluteUrl = dictionary.Aggregate(absoluteUrl, (current, keyValuePair) => current + (keyValuePair.Key + "=" + keyValuePair.Value + "&"));
            absoluteUrl = absoluteUrl.TrimEnd('&');

            HttpResponseMessage response = Client.GetAsync(absoluteUrl).Result;
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

My problem is if I try to debug this method, the debugging stops at the statement below.

```
HttpResponseMessage response = Client.GetAsync(absoluteUrl).Result;
```

It is neither throwing any exception, nor the debugger is passing through that statement. At the same time the browser hangs. I have made sure that I am passing a right url to `GetAsync` method. Still I am not able to figure out what is the problem. Please help.

Comment: Calling `.Result` will block the current thread until the task completes i.e. you'll be waiting until the result is received from the web service.

Comment: Yes. I wait for a while when debugging stops. Still debugger doesn't come to next statement.

Comment: What do you expect? The thread is blocking, waiting for the result of the task. You should await the call and have a sensible timeout in place.